# Can not refactor code in PyDev Eclipse (AST not generated)

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using Eclipse Juno, together with Pydev 2.75 and Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3.

Now, when I am trying to refactor some code by renaming one of my functions, I get the following pop-up message:

```
AST not generated (syntax error)
```

I have googled this message but it seems to be undocumented? I am totally new to the topic of AST, and don't even know where to move from here in order to resolve this issue (except perhaps by manually renaming all the functions occurences in the code, which would be painful). Any hints on how to get this functionality back and running?

Edit:
It appears that I am also  unable to import between modules in my program. Standard library imports work though.

Comment: Ok, so I've been palying around a bit an was able to replicate this error on my Linux machine with Eclipse Juno and PyDev 2.75. So it seems machine and platform independent. Because I had not enough time to dwell into AST I took the 0-option and upgraded to PyDev 3.0. After the upgrade AST kicked back in. What is interesting, after the upgrade, IDE found indentation errors in my Python code (one additional whitespace before docstrings).

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran across this issue it turned out to be a simple syntax error that I wasn't paying attention to. I had started writing a line of code, decided to change a method name before I finished that line, highlighted the method name, hit control-shift-R and got this error. It sounds like you were running into something different perhaps, but I wasted a ridiculous amount of time chasing down info on AST when all I needed to do was comment out the uncompleted line of code